# function returns only None values when replacing pandas column values by regex match

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Goal: replace values in column `que_text` with matches of re.search pattern. Else `None`

Problem: Receiving only `None` values in `que_text_new` column although regex pattern is thoroughly tested!

```
def override(s):
    x = re.search(r'(an|frage(\s+ich)?)\s+d(i|ı)e\s+Staatsreg(i|ı)erung(.*)(Dresden(\.|,|\s+)?)?', str(s), flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE))
    if x :
        return x.group(5)
    return None
df2['que_text_new'] = df2['que_text'].apply(override)
```

What am i doing wrong? removing `return None` doesent help. There must be some structural error within my function, i assume.

Comment: Will you please post a sample of your dataframe? It's nearly impossible to help without that.

Comment: Where is `s` used the `override` function?

Comment: dont know, i assumed `s` is supposed to be an arbitrary placeholder just like in loops?!

Comment: No, you need an input string as the 2nd argument to the `re.search` method. Before editing the question, you had `str(s)` (that is why I mention it in  my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern with a single capturing group and then simpy use `Series.str.extract` and chain `.fillna(np.nan)` to fill the non-matched values with `NaN`:

```py
pattern = r'(?s)(?:an|frage(?:\s+ich)?)\s+d[iı]e\s+Staatsreg[iı]erung(.*)'
df2['que_text_new'] = df2['que_text'].astype(str).str.extract(pattern).fillna(np.nan)
```

Not sure you need `.astype(str)`, but there is `str(s)` in your code, so it might be safer with this part.

Here,

- Capturing groups with single char alternatives are converted to *character classes*, e.g. `(i|ı)` -> `[iı]`
- Other capturing groups are converted to non-capturing ones, i.e. `(` -> `(?:`.
- To make `np.nan` work do not forget to `import numpy as np`.
- `(?s)` is an in-pattern `re.DOTALL` option.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor. Do you have an idea why i would get `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 7, placement implies 1` on my test dataset? I will add representative data in a sec

Comment: You did not use my solution. Use a regex with just one capturing group.

Comment: Ok i see. I assume there is no solution with multiple capturing groups? Then i will give you the actual regex. I updated the question text. I need `.group(5)` of that regex

Comment: @id345678  I do not see the point in using so many groups if you need just one.

Comment: If I keep it like i did, it does stop at `(Dresden(\.|,|\s+)?)?`, if it finds that thing and otherwise captures everything until the end of the string, right?

Comment: @id345678 No and your regex did not work like that. If you need that functionality use `r'(?s)(?:an|frage(?:\s+ich)?)\s+d[iı]e\s+Staatsreg[iı]erung(.*?)(?:Dresden|$)'`, `(\.|,|\s+)?` is redundant.

Comment: aaaaa I need to rewrite a lot of code now. Thanks for making that clear to me though.

Comment: I assume you did not quite understand why I suggested this kind of solution. 1) `Series.str.extract` in Pandas is handy to extract (parts of) matches into new column(s) and to do that, you need to use *capturing* groups in the pattern around those parts you want to extract. 2) Those groupings you do not need to extract into new column(s) should be *non-capturing* (`(?:...)`). 3) Only "capturing groups with **single char alternatives** are converted to *character classes*". If you have `(\.|,|\s+)` you can't use `[.,\s+]`, it would match a different thing.

Comment: @id345678 `(\.|,|\s+)` can be written as `(?:\.|,|\s+)` or `(?:[.,]|\s+)`

Comment: I think i got the concept of surrounding the part i want with non-capturing groups, but it certainly helps if you write it as clearly as you just did. I was going to ask how pandas knows which capturing group it should extract to the new column, since in your solution `pattern` has 2 capture groups. regex101 says there is capturing group `0` and capture group `1`. Obvjously i want the content of capturing group 1 `(.*?)` and i think it does it like this. But i dont know why it doesent throw error: there is more than 1 capture group to extract

Comment: @id345678 `r'(?s)(?:an|frage(?:\s+ich)?)\s+d[iı]e\s+Staatsreg[iı]erung(.*)'` contains only 1 capturing group. `(?s)` is not counted as a capturing group as it is an inline modifier. You must have edited the pattern. If you need help, please share the regex101.com link to the regex you are currently using.

Comment: Does `(?s)(?:an|frage(?:\s+ich)?)\s+d[iı]e\s+Staatsreg[iı]erung(.*?)(?:Dresden|$)` have 2? The first being e.g. `frage ich die Staatsregierung Seit wann Dresden` while the second is then `Seit wann`

Comment: @id345678 There is only *one* capturing group (capturing " Seit wann "), see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AkrpE7/1). Trim the value with `\s*`s, see  [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AkrpE7/2).

Comment: Okay so i just ignore that it says `Group 0`. Btw. How do i share regex101 links with my input saved? Copying the url dosent work

Comment: @id345678 Group 0 is *the match value*. Capturing groups start with ID=1. Click *Save regex* on the left at the top. Then share the link.